# How to use Google ML KIT to recognize facial expressions Determine whether a person is smiling or has their eyes closed

Tags: face-recognition, face-detection, google-mlkit

In the Google ML KIT documentation https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection
it's mentioned that facial expressions can be recognized.
However, I was unable to find any sample code or tutorials demonstrating how this works.
If anyone has information or resources that could assist, please share.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbn2Z.png)

I've been searching but have only found tutorials on face detection.
I'm hoping someone could share resources specifically about face recognition